# How to have alternating line colors for a Winforms RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

Something that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a line-like property where I could do?:

```
foreach line ...
    line.BackColor = Colors.Gray;
```

`Lines[i]` property returns just a string.

Comment: Just select the text until you reach a semicolon. Then set the .SelectionBackColor (or whatever corresponding property) to Gray.

Comment: Thanks but will it set the whole line back color or until the last character on that line? Because I want the whole line whether it's empty or not.

Comment: I don't think RTF can do that at all.

Comment: I read somewhere that one could make this control transparent and put an image behind where the text would show over this image. Is that possible? I could do it like that, I just don't know how to make the RTB transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A not so great solution would be to append extra text onto each line and then highlight the full text.  So something like this:

```
// Update lines to have extra length past length of window
string[] linez = new string[richTextBox1.Lines.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
   linez[i] = richTextBox1.Lines[i] + new string(' ', 1000);
}
richTextBox1.Clear();
richTextBox1.Lines = linez;

for(int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
   int first = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
   richTextBox1.Select(first, richTextBox1.Lines[i].Length);
   richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = (i % 2 == 0) ? Color.Red : Color.White;
   richTextBox1.SelectionColor = (i % 2 == 0) ? Color.Black : Color.Green;
}
richTextBox1.Select(0,0);
```

It would look like this:

[image: RichTextBox with colored lines]