# Rich Text Box how to highlight text block

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I need a certain portion of my text in RTB to be highlighted not in the sense of changing the font style/color, but in the sense of making a block selection with a particular color. This is similar to how Visual Studio highlights a line during debug mode.

How can I accomplish this feature using RTB or rather, is it even possible? If it isn't possible, I'd like to hear another way of performing the above task.

Comment: I think you are looking for [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/). On the other hand if you want to do this by yourself in RTB then you can do it by first finding the `lineNumber` using [TextBoxBase.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property. Then ... //Select the line from it's number richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber); richTextBox.Select(startIndex, length); //Set the selected text fore and background color richTextBox.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; richTextBox.SelectionBackColor= System.Drawin

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have alternating line colors for a Winforms RichTextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982006/how-to-have-alternating-line-colors-for-a-winforms-richtextbox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/).

On the other hand if you want to do this by yourself in RTB then you can do it by first finding the `lineNumber` using [TextBoxBase.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property. Then ...

```
//Select the line from it's number
startIndex = richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber);
richTextBox.Select(startIndex, length);

//Set the selected text fore and background color
richTextBox.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
richTextBox.SelectionBackColor= System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

Comment: Aren't you ignoring the `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()` return value instead of save it into `startIndex` variable?

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can set the BackColor of a RichTextBox Selection using the [RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor) Property.

```
int blockStart = 1; //arbitrary numbers to test
int blockLength = 15;
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = blockStart;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = blockLength;
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I have created CustomRichTextBox to achieve this.

The source code a long with scenario is explained here. If you interested then you can reuse this usercontrol directly without worry about much

Scenario

https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/windows8/customwpfrichtextboxwithcolorchangeandhighlightfunctionality

source code:

https://github.com/boobalaninfo/CustomRichTextBoxWithHighligh