# how to can Change the richtextbox default blue highlight color?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been looking for the way to change the richtextbox highlight color when a user select text or event mouse move. Windows uses blue as default color.But I want it to be green And blue by default no longer exists.

```
  private void richIndicateText_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        richIndicateText.Select(0, 50);
        richIndicateText.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think that you need something like in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183599/rich-text-box-how-to-highlight-text-block

Comment: @MarekDerdzinski,But not removed entirely blue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.richIndicateText.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(richIndicateText_MouseMove); //hook

 this.richIndicateText.MouseClick -= richIndicateText_MouseMove; //unhook

 private void richIndicateText_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    richIndicateText.Select(0, 50);
    richIndicateText.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;

}
```

I will try my best, maybe something like this ?

Comment: No, this is not what I need to fix

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the desired behavior is not possible in Windows Forms (details [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/692bb113-737d-462c-adef-dffc465a1282/richtextbox-selection-color?forum=winforms)). The workaround would be to use a WPF RichTextBox in the Windows Form through [ElementHost](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ElementHost&oq=ElementHost&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.793j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).