# Highlighting Unbalanced Parentheses in RichTextBox C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, stack, highlight, parentheses

I currently have a Windows Form set up which takes a math expression inside a RichTextBox, and searches the expression for any unbalanced parentheses.  My form consists of the RichTextBox, and a button that says "Check Parens".  I am also trying to check for unbalanced parentheses using a stack as well.  What I want is to somehow indicate which parentheses are unbalanced.  I would like to do this by either highlighting or bolding the parentheses inside the RichTextBox.  Is there a way of doing this with the code I have set up right now?  Here's my code below, and any constructive feedback would be much appreciated!

```
public partial class checkParentheses : Form
{
    const char leftParens = '(';
    const char rightParens = ')';

    public checkParentheses()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void checkParensButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;
        checkBalancedParens(mathEquation.Text, out value);
    }

    bool checkBalancedParens(string expression, out int error)
    {
        var parens = new Stack<int>(expression.Length);//Create stack
        error = -1; //Error at -1

        for (int i = 0; i < expression.Length; i++)//Check for unbalanced Parentheses
        {
            char p = expression[i];
            if (p == leftParens)//if p finds left parens
            {
                parens.Push(i);//push to top of stack
            }
            else if (p == rightParens)//if p finds right parens
            {
                if (parens.Count == 0)//if stack has zero items
                {
                    error = i + 1;
                    return false;
                }
                parens.Pop();//Returns to top of stack
            }
        }
        if (parens.Count > 0)//if stack has more than 0 items
        {
            error = parens.Peek() + 1; //Peek at top of stack
            MessageBox.Show("Unbalanced");
            return false;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Balanced");//Otherwise, expression is balanced
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: given the solution below, this is inferior. Example still included if you want to bold the text. You could replace the HighlightOffenders method with

```
private void HighlightOffenders(IEnumerable<int> listOfIndexes)
    {

        foreach (var index in listOfIndexes.Reverse())
        {

            mathEquation.Select(index,1);
            mathEquation.SelectionFont = new Font(mathEquation.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }

    }
```

So, you should keep track of both left paren indexes and right paren indexes. Then just pop matching pairs off of their respective stacks.

As far as displaying the text, I don't know if this is the **best** way, but this is a way that will work. It requires rebuilding the string, but it will put the correct results in the RichTextBox. You'll need to ignore the fact that my form is called "Form1", and replace that with "checkParentheses". There is probably a way to draw highlighting on top of the actual characters, but I'm not familiar with it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const char leftParenChar = '(';
    const char rightParenChar = ')';

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void checkParensButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBalancedParens(mathEquation.Text);
    }

    bool checkBalancedParens(string expression)
    {
        var leftParensIndexes = new Stack<int>(expression.Length);
        var rightParensIndexes = new Stack<int>(expression.Length);
        var isError = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < expression.Length; i++)//Check for unbalanced Parentheses
        {
            char p = expression[i];
            if (p == leftParenChar)//if p finds left parens
            {
                leftParensIndexes.Push(i);//push to top of stack
            }
            else if (p == rightParenChar)//if p finds right parens
            {
                rightParensIndexes.Push(i);

                //keep a record if there is an error, but don't stop yet.
                if (leftParensIndexes.Count == 0)
                {
                    isError = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //eliminate the matching pair if it exists
                    rightParensIndexes.Pop();
                    leftParensIndexes.Pop();
                }


            }
        }
        if (leftParensIndexes.Count > 0)//if stack has more than 0 items
        {
            isError = true;
        }
        HighlightOffenders(rightParensIndexes.Concat(leftParensIndexes));
        return !isError;
    }

    private void HighlightOffenders(IEnumerable<int> listOfIndexes)
    {
        var text = mathEquation.Text;
        mathEquation.Clear();
        int lastIndex = 0; //store the last index you finished at (for string math)
        int count = 0; //the number of items that we've added (also for string math)

        foreach (var index in listOfIndexes.Reverse())
        {

            mathEquation.AppendText(text.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex - count));
            mathEquation.SelectionFont = new Font(mathEquation.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            mathEquation.AppendText(text.Substring(index,1));
            mathEquation.SelectionFont = new Font(mathEquation.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
            lastIndex = index;
            count++;

        }
        mathEquation.AppendText(text.Substring(lastIndex + count-1, text.Length - lastIndex - count + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, and it makes sense how you did it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Highlighting text in RichEdit described here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183599/)
. Complete solution:

```
private void checkParensButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // clean up previous selection
  mathEquation.SelectAll();
  mathEquation.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

  var indexes = EnumerateUnbalancedParentheses(mathEquation.Text);
  foreach (var index in indexes)
  {
    mathEquation.Select(index, 1);
    mathEquation.SelectionBackColor = Color.Aqua;
  }
}

private static IEnumerable<int> EnumerateUnbalancedParentheses(string expression)
{
  var openingParentheses = new Stack<int>();
  var closingParentheses = new Stack<int>();

  for (var i = 0; i < expression.Length; ++i)
  {
    var symbol = expression[i];
    if (symbol == '(')
    {
      openingParentheses.Push(i);
    }
    else if (symbol == ')')
    {
      if (openingParentheses.Count > 0)
        openingParentheses.Pop();
      else
        closingParentheses.Push(i);
    }
  }

  return openingParentheses.Concat(closingParentheses);
}
```